# Images On ImageSwitcher Cannot Align to Center

Tags: android

I Have Image Switcher that will change images every x seconds. 
It works fine if i set the image to switcher using setImageDrawable. But The images are not aligned vertical center. Below are my Layout

```
    <RelativeLayout
           android:id="@+id/galleryimage"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
           android:background="@drawable/gallerymain2"
           android:clipToPadding="true"
           android:padding="5dp" >

           <ImageSwitcher
                 android:id="@+id/image_switcher"
                 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:foregroundGravity="center"   />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Then I used switcher.setForeground instead, It align properly but the animation doesnt no kick in. Anyone have ideas how to fix this? thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should override makeView() in your java file:

```
public View makeView() {
    ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);
    imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
    imageView.setLayoutParams(new ImageSwitcher.LayoutParams(
        LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
    return imageView;
  }
```